# My input is not proceeding to the next page

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have created a form where the user will enter some information and the email will have to be validated before the user can proceed to the next page (thankyou.html) however when i input every thing correctly into the form the email gets validated but i cannot get to the next page...i cant figure out what im doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function validate()
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("text1").value;
            var regx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.([a-z]{3})$/;
            var uname = document.getElementById("name");
            var title = document.getElementById("title1");
            var comment = document.getElementById("cmt");


        if(regx.test(text))
            {
            document.getElementById("lbltext").innerHTML="you may proceed";
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.visibility="visible";  
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.color="green";
            }
        else{
            document.getElementById("lbltext").innerHTML="invalid email";
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.color="black";
            }

        }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form onsubmit = "return validate()" action = "thankyou.html" class = "input"><br><br>
    <p style = "text-decoration: underline; color: white;">comment :</p><br>
    <input id= "name" placeholder= "Name" type= "text" style = "height: 25px; width:250px;"/><br><br>
    <input id = "text1" placeholder = "Email" type= "text" style = "height: 25px; width: 250px;"/><p style = "font-size: 25px; color: red; display: inline-block;">*</p><label id= "lbltext" style = "color: black;visibility: hidden"></label><br><br>
    <input id= "title1" placeholder= "title" type= "text" style = "height: 25px; width: 500px;"/><br><br>
    <textarea id= "cmt" placeholder= "Comment" type= "text" style = "height: 250px; width: 500px;"></textarea><br><br>
    <button onClick="validate()" type="button" style = "color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color:  #9933ff; width: 75px; height: 30px;float: right; margin-right: 90px; border:thick; border-color: black;">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `return validate()`, The `onSubmit` is expecting a boolean return value from `validate()`. So, If you want to submit the form you should return `true`, If not return `false`.

**NOTE**

- If you want to access the form data in next page, You should set `name` property for your input fields.
- Since you are using `onSubmit`, You don't need to put `onClick` to the `button`. And the button type should be `submit` **not** `button`.

```js
    function validate()
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("text1").value;
            var regx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.([a-z]{3})$/;
            var uname = document.getElementById("name");
            var title = document.getElementById("title1");
            var comment = document.getElementById("cmt");


        if(regx.test(text))
            {
            document.getElementById("lbltext").innerHTML="you may proceed";
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.visibility="visible";  
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.color="green";
            return true;
            }
        else{
            document.getElementById("lbltext").innerHTML="invalid email";
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById("lbltext").style.color="black";
            return false;
            }

        }
```

```html
<body>
<form onsubmit = "return validate()" action = "thankyou.html" class = "input"><br><br>
    <p style = "text-decoration: underline; color: white;">comment :</p><br>
    <input id= "name" placeholder= "Name" type= "text" style = "height: 25px; width:250px;"/><br><br>
    <input id = "text1" placeholder = "Email" type= "text" style = "height: 25px; width: 250px;"/><p style = "font-size: 25px; color: red; display: inline-block;">*</p><label id= "lbltext" style = "color: black;visibility: hidden"></label><br><br>
    <input id= "title1" placeholder= "title" type= "text" style = "height: 25px; width: 500px;"/><br><br>
    <textarea id= "cmt" placeholder= "Comment" type= "text" style = "height: 250px; width: 500px;"></textarea><br><br>
    <button type="submit" style = "color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color:  #9933ff; width: 75px; height: 30px;float: right; margin-right: 90px; border:thick; border-color: black;">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it looks like you're just going to the tankyou.html immediately after validation. It seems to me like you don't need the green 'you may proceed'. You could clean up your code a little.

```
    if(regx.test(text) === false)
    {
        document.getElementById("lbltext").innerHTML="invalid email";
        document.getElementById("lbltext").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("lbltext").style.color="black";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
```